# How to work out this single-question answer?

Tags: difference

> Who is the man running ***_*__** Lucy?
>
> The options are the following:
>    A. after
>   B. behind
>   C. in
>   front
>    D. across

I think the options A & B  are right.  But this is single-choice question . If they are both right, how to distinguish "run after" and "run behind"?

Comment: Isn't the 'running after' correct answer?

Comment: I think they are both right. In this question, "running behind" means the man is actually running, and he is behind Lucy; "running after" can mean either "the man loves Lucy so he is chasing her" or just like "running behind". So maybe it depends on the context.

Comment: Since "running after" someone is highly idiomatic, and the question seems to be on a simple "which preposition do we use to indicate a position"-level, I would select B as the correct answer. A is definitely not _wrong_ but it has a (number of) much more advanced meaning(s).

Comment: Running behind someone is very common if you are talking about a group of people running. But yes, _if_ this is an idiomatic exercise, it should be answer A. As always, context :) Maybe the OP can tell us a bit more about this question?

Comment: @user48070: You should provide the source for this "question". Lately we've been getting quite a few such "badly-composed" exercises. This one is particularly bad because all except **to run in front Lucy** are perfectly credible things to do *in context*. Also because in addition to the "literal" sense of the prepositions, **to run after Lucy** can be a "phrasal verb" usage meaning **to woo her**, and **to run across her** can be a phrasal verb meaning **to meet her by chance**. It's a *very* poor quality multiple choice question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This question is from a test paper, so I can't give you an exact source for this question.

Comment: Well, you must have got it from *somewhere*. If you have a choice, get your tests from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Mea culpa!

This is very tricky but I think we should look this problem like this -

[run after someone/somebody](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+after) - try to get the attention of someone (opposite sex). See both the meanings on the page.

This example has a *man* and *Luch* (girl) so *run after* fits **but then**, if you look at other options, it gives hint of asking the **position** of the runner. So,

> [run behind someone/something](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/run+behind) - to travel along behind someone or something, running

The sentence has *Lucy* and thus it marks off *run behind* as an idiom which means *being late*.

Comment: That idiom is only a problem if Lucy is not mentioned. I run behind Lucy only means one thing. On the other hand, I run after Lucy _is_ ambiguous. It can mean I am constantly busy cleaning up her mess, or actually, I am in love with her.

Comment: @oerkelens Thanks for pointing out. It's indeed tricky!

Comment: @oerkelens: I'd say that sense is more **woo, pursue romantically**, rather than **be in love with**. As defined in OED: *To endeavour to gain the companionship or society of, or bestow one's admiration and loyalty upon (a person); (in later use esp.) to seek the company of (a potential romantic or sexual partner).*

Comment: True, I lazily copied it from an earlier comment, but I wasn't completely happy with it either. Thank you for both pointing out my laziness and enhancing my description. :)

Comment: @MaulikV I disagree that individuals of opposite sex are a necessary part of the idiom _to run after someone_. I see your source mentioning it, but I dare say it is quite an old-fashioned approach in many people's eyes.

Comment: @oerkelens: There's only really one (or maybe two) idiomatic usage of "run after" these days - mainly confined to plural/unidentified "subjects" anyway. *"She's very pretty - all the boys are running after her"* is about the only sort of context you'll see the "wooing" sense now. The "other" one (without the "romantic" connotation) occurs in things like *"You won't lose weight by running after every fad diet"*, where "you" is usually "generic" (equivalent to "one"). They're not really even "idioms", imho - just fairly transparent figurative usages.